# How to get names of css classes of an element

Tags: c#, css, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have to check if an element was selected. The only way I can do it is to watch if an additional css class "selected" was added to this element.

So, my element looks like:

```
<div class="b-wide-option" data-bind="css: { selected: IsSelected }, click: Select, attr: { id: Id }, event: { mouseover: OnMouseOver, mouseout: OnMouseOut, touchstart: OnTouchClick }" id="2">
```

When I select it it looks like:

```
<div class="b-wide-option selected" data-bind="css: { selected: IsSelected }, click: Select, attr: { id: Id }, event: { mouseover: OnMouseOver, mouseout: OnMouseOut, touchstart: OnTouchClick }" id="2">
```

The css class "selected" is added. And I need to check if it was added or not. I use the next code:

```
string classes = element.GetAttribute("class");
```

But unfortunately it returns only the first class "b-wide-option" and don't return the second which I actually need.

Comment: Is the issue a timing issue? e.g. if you were to extract the class attribute 1 second later would you expect it to be there?

Comment: No, it's a static element. Once I selected it the class "selected" is present

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this

```
       element.getAttribute("className");
```

Hope this will help you to solve problem

Comment: No, he has only  word "class" not "className"

Comment: Do I have an atribute with the name of "className"?

Comment: use this element.getAttribute("className"); instead of element.getAttribute("class");

Answer (score 1):

I'm so sorry guys! I've just checked another element, my fault! 
The simple code as element.getAttribute("className"); and element.getAttribute("class"); works perfect, indeed!)

I wish moderator delited this question, I"m sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
getElementsByClassName('foo')
```

or u can  also use jquery

```
var className = $('.b-wide-option').attr('class');
```

or u can also use `.hasClass()` function.

```
var className = $('.b-wide-option').attr('class');
if($('.b-wide-option').hasClass('selected')){
//write your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class names by this:

```
element.Attributes["class"].ToString();
```